# Does AF0838 from ZNZ to CDG require deplaning and security at NBO?

Tags: air-travel, airports, bookings, nairobi, nbo

I have booked AF0838 from ZNZ (Zanzibar)to CDG (Paris - Charles de Gaule) and then upon getting my itinerary, it was broken into ZNZ-NBO (Nairobi - Jomo Kenyatta) NBO-CDG with the same flight number and a one hour stop at NBO.

Do we need to deplane and/or clear security again at NBO?

I ask because last time I transferred in NBO, they made me remove my fragile wood carvings from my carry-on and put it in my checked.  I’m hoping that WON’T be the case this time.

Have you flown this route?  Or do you otherwise know the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: I've flown some of these kinds of routes with a "technical stop". Like IST-PTY via BOG, and MAD-SLV via GUA. Never have I gotten off, they always de plane those whose destination was the technical stop, but those of us going on stayed on the plane. Check your ticket, if it says technical stop you should be good. Otherwise call the airline and check with them

Comment: Although, I just looked through the available flights from ZNZ to CGD and they are mostly jointly operated by Kenya Airways and AF, meaning there would be a true connection in NBO. Again, check your ticket/contact the airline.

Comment: AF836 and 838 are triangular flights CDG-ZNZ-NBO-CDG. I would expect that at some point they would want to get everybody out to clean the aircraft somewhere between the two “long” legs, but those are pretty short stops for an aircraft this size (787), so people travelling onwards probably stay on board. I have no experience with this flight, though, so it’s only a guess.